# How do I fix "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion...'?

Tags: java, warnings, unchecked-conversion

In the Java snippet:

```
SyndFeedInput fr = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed sf = fr.build(new XmlReader(myInputStream));
List<SyndEntry> entries = sf.getEntries();
```

the last line generates the warning

"The expression of type `List` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `List<SyndEntry>`"

What's an appropriate way to fix this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Since `getEntries` returns a raw `List`, it could hold anything.

The warning-free approach is to create a new `List<SyndEntry>`, then cast each element of the `sf.getEntries()` result to `SyndEntry` before adding it to your new list. `Collections.checkedList` does *not* do this checking for you—although it would have been possible to implement it to do so.

By doing your own cast up front, you're "complying with the warranty terms" of Java generics: if a `ClassCastException` is raised, it will be associated with a cast in the source code, not an invisible cast inserted by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks -- that's an interesting insight about the "warranty" and the invisible cast done by the compiler versus a cast done explicitly in my own code.

Comment: Yes, the value of un-reified generics is somewhat limited, but that is one thing it does provide. Just to clarify, this requires that your code compiles without type safety warnings.

Comment: Hi erickson, I agree that this indeed the best solution. Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion/2848268#2848268 for a generic version of this solution.

Answer (score 130):

This is a common problem when dealing with pre-Java 5 APIs. To automate the [solution from erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion/367673#367673), you can create the following generic method:

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
    List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
    for(Object o: c)
      r.add(clazz.cast(o));
    return r;
}
```

This allows you to do:

```
List<SyndEntry> entries = castList(SyndEntry.class, sf.getEntries());
```

Because this solution checks that the elements indeed have the correct element type by means of a cast, it is safe, and does not require `SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Regarding the method suggested by Bruno, Wouldnt this hurt application performance when having Lists with many elements?. Java would have to cast each and every one of them.

Comment: If you want guarantees, that is the cost.  Is there another less expensive option?  Obviously, if you have control over the invoked raw collection returning method, or even invoking the method or accessing the collection using a lazy-demand approach.  Anything that considers the entire collection after the method invocation?

Answer (score 29):

It looks like `SyndFeed` is not using generics.

You could either have an unsafe cast and a warning suppression:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<SyndEntry> entries = (List<SyndEntry>) sf.getEntries();
```

or call [Collections.checkedList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedList) - although you'll still need to suppress the warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<SyndEntry> entries = Collections.checkedList(sf.getEntries(), SyndEntry.class);
```

Comment: Since they both suppress the warning, any advantages to one or the other, or a preference? Thanks!

Also: is the cast necessary if the unchecked suppression is in place?

Comment: @Yar: Well, `Collections.checkedList` will prevent the addition of any non-SyndEntry elements later. I personally don't use `checkedList` much, but then I also don't often get into this unchecked cast situation anyway...

Answer (score 10):

Did you write the `SyndFeed`?

Does `sf.getEntries` return List or `List<SyndEntry>`?  My guess is it returns `List` and changing it to return `List<SyndEntry>` will fix the problem.

If `SyndFeed` is part of a library, I don't think you can remove the warning without adding the `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotation to your method.

Comment: You can also add an explicit cast.

Comment: A cast will just produce another warning, since the code is not type safe.

Comment: `SyndFeed` comes from https://rometools.github.io/rome/ROMEReleases/ROME1.0Release.html. The problem seems to be fixed in more recent versions of Rome like the ones found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome/1.9.0

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Guava and all you want to do is iterate through your values:

```
for(SyndEntry entry: Iterables.filter(sf.getEntries(), SyndEntry.class){
  ...
}
```

If you need an actual List you can use

```
List<SyndEntry> list = Lists.newArrayList(
    Iterables.filter(sf.getEntries(), SyndEntry.class));
```

or

```
List<SyndEntry> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(
    Iterables.filter(sf.getEntries(), SyndEntry.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the javadoc for the class `SyndFeed` (I guess you are referring to the class `com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed`), the method getEntries() doesn't return `java.util.List<SyndEntry>`, but returns just `java.util.List`.

So you need an explicit cast for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SyndFeedInput fr = new SyndFeedInput();
SyndFeed sf = fr.build(new XmlReader(myInputStream));
List<?> entries = sf.getEntries();
```

Comment: Even if the code provided here solves the problem, i'd encourage you to briefly explain why it does that. Please explain why the posted answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put @SuppressWarning("unchecked") on each sf.getEntries() call, you can always make a wrapper that will return List.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results#118976)

Answer (score 0):

Even easier

`return new ArrayList<?>(getResultOfHibernateCallback(...))`

Comment: Then you would deal with proper casting (re-casting?) at usage time for each element in ArrayList<?>.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Bruno De Fraine is great. However if the size of input argument "Collection<?> c" is 0 then the routine crashes with null pointer.
I suggest a minor improvement to avoid this (and I give the version for HashSet):

```
public static <T> HashSet<T> castHashSet(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
  int cSize = (c == null) ? 0 : c.size();
  HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>(cSize);
  if (c != null) {
    for (Object o : c)
      hashSet.add(clazz.cast(o));
    }
    return hashSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 style

```
private static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
        return c.stream().map(o -> clazz.cast(o)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```