# Java generics infering type

Tags: java, generics

my IDE generates a warning when i use the following code:

```
aMethod(List.class);
```

"Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to ..."
Sadly when i try to let the IDE fix it, it doesn't work. What is the proper syntax to infere the generic type ? Thx in advance for any help.

edit:

Signature of the method:

```
public static <T> T aMethod(Class<T> clazz)
```

Lets make it simple and say the type i wanna refere to is `String`.

kuku

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `aMethod`.

Comment: maybe duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion

Comment: It would make detective work much easier if you would not cut what it needs to conform to...  Or provide a signature of `aMethod`

Comment: Signature of the method: public static <T> T aMethod(Class<T> clazz)
does it matter what it needs to be conform to ? Lets make it simple -> String.

Comment: the code you show above compiles fine in IntelliJ with JDK5, without warning. What detail is missing from your post?

Answer (score 3):

If You want only to remove the waring from the code:

```
aMethod(Class<?> clazz);
```

For classes that inherit the Collection class You can use something this:

```
public <T extends Collection<?>> void clazz(Class<T> clazz);
```

Answer (score 1):

`List.class` is what is known as a raw type.

Generics use type erasure to remove the parametrized types from the compiled code.  The typesafe checks are done solely at compile time.  It's the compiler which make sure you only add Strings to a List.

At runtime, the String is gone, and your `List<String>` functions exactly as a pre-generics List would.  So you are passing it to a method which is trying to guess what the `T` is in `List<T>`.  But it will never be able to determine this, since the information will be gone.

Since the types can't be matched, the compiler is warning you that your code may allow non-typesafe access to your list.  That is, since `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` are treated the same at runtime, and are both represented by `List.class`, you might be setting yourself up for a situation where at runtime, your code might attempt to add a `String` to a `List<Integer>` which will fail.

**See Also**

[Generics in the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.2)

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the generics chapter in Effective Java SE, which covers *exactly* this issue.

Comment: The generic method is from a library i'm using. So do i understand correctly that my only option here is to supress the warning. I thought i could pass the information that my List contains Strings to the method.