# Need to filter a list to a particular subclass using generics

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I have a `List` that contains a certain superclass (like Vehicle), and I would like to write a method that returns the objects in that list that are instances of a certain subclass (like Car).

So far I have this, but it generates a typical "unchecked" operation compiler warning:

```
public <T extends Vehicle> List<T> getVehiclesOfType(Class<T> type) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (Vehicle vehicle : getVehicles()) {
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(vehicle.getClass())) {
            result.add(type.cast(vehicle)); // Compiler warning here
            // Note, (T)vehicle generates an "Unchecked cast" warning (IDE can see this one)
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

```
Warning: Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

I'm ok with any other method of accomplishing this (I couldn't find anything in `Collections`, but it's possible some JDK method can do it), but ideally it would provide the following interface:

```
List<Car> cars = getVehiclesOfType(Car.class);
```

I would like to know why I was receiving a compiler warning on the original code, though.

Comment: @Codemwnci, @sblundy, oops, sorry.  Standard "unchecked operation" warning. Question edited to add this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this warning. What is the return type of getVehicles()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a warning because there's no way for the compiler (or the IDE) to know that the cast is safe, without understanding the meaning of `isAssignableFrom()`. But `isAssignableFrom()` isn't a language feature, it's just a library method. As far as the compiler's concerned, it's the same as if you'd said

```
    if (type.getName().contains("Elvis")) {
        result.add(type.cast(vehicle));
    }
```

However, you know what `isAssignableFrom()` means, so you know it's safe. This is exactly the sort of situation `@SuppressWarnings` is meant for.

Comment: P.S. I would use type.isInstance() myself.

Comment: So does the compiler give this warning **anytime** `Class.cast()` is used?

Comment: May depend on the compiler. With IDEA 9 and JDK 1.6 (experimenting now), I don't get a warning even for a completely unsafe use that leads to a ClassCastException. My guess is that an `instanceof` check -- where you can make one -- might eliminate the warning, because then it's known at compile time to be safe. But I don't really know.

Comment: Like I said, the IDE doesn't show the warning, but when I compile it does.  Doesn't yours?  You should be right about the `instanceof` check but that is not possible here (dynamic class object)

Comment: I don't get the warning either from IDEA or from javac -- which in the case of javac at least is a little curious. Could be a matter of compiler flags / IDE preferences. (Are you using Eclipse? There are a lot of subtle differences between the Eclipse compiler and javac -- usually unimportant, but you do run into them from time to time.) Regardless, it doesn't surprise me that you're getting a warning, and suppressing it seems like the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
if (type.isInstance(vehicle)) {
    result.add((T)(vehicle));
}
```

Does the compiler still complain like that?

---

But if I were you I'd use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), that will make your method a one-liner:

```
public <T extends Vehicle> List<T> getVehiclesOfType(Class<T> type) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(getVehicles(), type));
}
```

Comment: Yep, see edits to original question.  The one I originally posted was a IDE-hidden warning, but compiler messages showed it.  `(T)` makes a different, IDE-visible warning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler isn't smart enough to know that vehicle is of class "type".  This is a runtime check and the compiler doesn't do that kind of analysis.  There are lots of situations like this.  For example I use   if (true) return;  to exit out of a function early during debugging all the time.  If I use just return, the compiler realizes that there is unreachable code, but with the conditional, the compiler doesn't realize that it's impossible to get into that branch.

Consider if you replace your conditional with if (false) {.  The code has no chance of throwing an exception but still contains an unsafe cast.

Basically the compiler is saying, "I can't confirm that this is safe so it's up to you to make sure you know what you are doing."  Your code isn't broken, you just need to exercise caution.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

> I would like to know why I was
>   receiving a compiler warning on the
>   original code, though.

*1st:*
Look at the code of Class: it does hide the cast for you. Normally casting to any arbitrary type (T) should be a warning but Class.cast actually checks and ignores the compiler warning(nonsense).

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
        throw new ClassCastException();
    return (T) obj;
}
```

*2nd*
That being said: Generics warnings is the 1st thing to disable. Having mixture of old code and now just doesn't worth suppress warning, nor I'd care. I am just waiting to see how generics reduce ClassCastException and it's probably true in only one case: using `add` instead `addAll` (put/putAll)

Answer (score 0):

You might be stuck with adding `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` to the method

Comment: I'm willing to accept this as the answer, if you can explain why.  We are under instruction to remove or explain any warning suppression.

Answer (score 0):

You are operating on Vehicle, which is a superclass and you try to downcast to a subclass of Vehicle. This is always an unsafe cast and will earn you a compiler warning.

So while you can cast from `Car` to `Vehicle` without warning (since `Car extends Vehicle`), the compiler has no way of knowing that the variable typed as `Vehicle` is actually a car.

By using a cast (either by using `(Car)` or `cast(..)`), you are telling the compiler that you know better.
The compiler hates people and still hands out a warning to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you're taking the wrong approach. Generics in Java are a [compile-time only feature](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html). You *know* what kind of list you need at compile-time so just create a helper method that returns the right kind of list:

```
public static List<Car> getCars( List<Vehicle> vlist ){ /* code here */ }
```

Add the helper method to the class in question and then in your code just do:

```
List<Car> cars = Cars.getCars( getVehicles() );
```

No casting issues at all. A bit more code to write, but you could also create overloaded versions that returned only blue cars, only red cars, etc.

Comment: Interesting. This is a good option to consider, however I'm not crazy about the idea of having to write the method for every type I have.  That's why I wanted to have a single method.  But, I appreciate the new angle.

Comment: You really only have two options as I see it. Either you create the individual helper methods as mentioned above, or you create a single method getVehiclesOfType in your Vehicle superclass that returns a List<Object> and you cast the result to the appropriate List<T> type -- but that would generate the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple answers to this question claim that the warning is due to the fact that the compiler can't **statically verify** that the cast cannot fail. Although the compiler indeed cannot verify that, that's no reason to give a warning! If the compiler would flag warnings for all casts that can't be verified statically, that banishes all meaningful casts, because when a cast can be verified statically, you generally don't need to be doing the cast in the first place. In other words, the entire point of a cast operation is that it *can* fail at runtime, which is a perfectly fine situation that is handled with a `ClassCastException`.

The "unchecked cast" warning on the other hand, happens when you do a cast for which there is **insufficient type information to verify the cast at runtime**. This can happen because of the erasure of type arguments at runtime. Suppose that you cast something of static type `List<?>` to `List<Vehicle>`. At runtime, objects of both of these types simply have the class `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` as their only runtime type information, without type arguments. So the compiler can't insert any code that will verify at runtime that the object is indeed a `List` of `Vehicle`. So the compiler does nothing, but raises an "unchecked cast" warning.

This is a useful warning, because you may run into a problem when you start using the result of the cast. Since the result has static type `List<Vehicle>`, you may write code that treats elements from the list as a `Vehicle`, without having to write a cast. But there is actually still a cast at runtime, and it will fail when the `List` turns out to contain anything that is not a `Vehicle`. So you may get a `ClassCastException` at a point where you did not expect it.

The safe way to handle such a conversion from `List<?>` to `List<Vehicle>`, is to iterate over each of the elements, cast them to `Vehicle` (something you *can* verify at runtime and which will raise a `ClassCastException` at a well defined point), and add them to a new list. I wrote some generic code to do precisely that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion/2848268#2848268).