# TreeMap generic argument warning

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings, unchecked

```
Map<Date, Integer> m = new HashMap<Date, Integer>(); // line 1
Map<Date, Integer> sMap = new TreeMap(m);            // line 2
```

Line 2 gives this error:

> Type safety: The expression of type TreeMap needs unchecked conversion
>   to conform to Map

The solution I found is this: [How do I fix "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion...'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion)

But, is it safe to simply `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or is there a scenario when my code will failed. More generally, when can we safely add the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: Why not ? TreeMap<Date, Integer>(m); ?

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying the generic types of the TreeMap when you instantiate it.

```
Map<Date, Integer> m = new HashMap<Date, Integer>(); // line 1
Map<Date, Integer> sMap = new TreeMap<Date,Integer>(m);
```

This answer assumes you are using java.util.TreeMap.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Are you using java.util.TreeMap ? It should accept generic types.  See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: @JohnJohnGa no problem happens to everyone.  Glad I could help, did that fix your issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java 7, you can use the [diamond syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

```
Map<Date, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
Map<Date, Integer> sMap = new TreeMap<>(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is:

```
1. Map<Date, Integer> m = new HashMap<Date, Integer>();
2. Map<Date, Integer> sMap = new TreeMap<Date, Integer>(m);
```

You can also supress the "unchecked" warnings if you are sure about the generic type. In this case, you are.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, adding generic parameters to the TreeMap resolves the problem, as the compiler can now **guarantee** that no invalid casts will happen. If you omit the generic parameters the compiler cannot give you this guarantee and therefore warns you. Then it is your responsibility that only objects of the correct type are stored in the TreeMap.

If you are you sure that only the correct objects are put into the TreeMap you can safely ignore the warning. If it fails and you encounter class cast exceptions on runtime, it is your own fault (:

Generally speaking if you supress a warning you are effectively ignoring a hint of the compiler that there may be a problem in your code. But the compiler is dumb and there are situations where you can safely say that no problems will occur (e.g. you have other checks in place or a design that does not permit the errors to happen). If that is the case you can suppress the warning.