# Casting to List<SomeType> issues an unchecked cast warning while casting to SomeType does not

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-safety

Why does this:

```
public <T> List<byte[]> getData(T data) {
    Location loc = (Location) data;
    // ...
}
```

not generate any warnings, while this:

```
public <T> List<byte[]> getData(T data) {
    List<ScanResult> scanRes = (List<ScanResult>) data;
    // ...
}
```

generates `Type safety: Unchecked cast from T to List<ScanResult>`?

How can I resolve the warning?
As a design is this kind of method declaration a smell?

```
public <T> List<byte[]> getData(T data)
```

is an interface method implemented in different classes with different data types - the first line of all implementations is such a cast

Comment: Note that having the method generic doesn't buy anything - it might as well be `public List<byte[]> getData(Object data)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the warning because the cast `(List<ScanResult>) data` is not safe. Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), `List<ScanResult>` will be `List` during runtime, so there will be no real type check regarding the element type of the list. That is, that cast will succeed even if you get `List<String>` as a parameter and later you will get a `ClassCastException` when you try to access the list:

```
ScanResult result = data.get(0); // ClassCastException: String
```

One way to avoid it is making the interface generic:

```
public interface DataProvider<T> {
    public List<byte[]> getData(T data);
}
```

And then define the specific type argument at implementations:

```
public class DataProviderFromLocation implements DataProvider<Location> {
    public List<byte[]> getData(Location data) {
    }
}

public class DataProviderFromScanResultList implements DataProvider<List<ScanResult>> {
    public List<byte[]> getData(List<ScanResult> data) {
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is suitable for your needs.

Comment: And why is `Location loc = (Location) data;` type safe ? If I call `getData("some string")` wont it fail in `Location loc = (Location) "some string";` again with CCE ? +1 for the parametrized interface idea

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `(Location) data` is type safe since `Location` is not generic type, `unchecked cast` warning is emitted only when casting to a generic type since the type argument is lost due to type erasure (and only `List` "remains" in your case).

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Think of it this way: at runtime, `T` has been erased to `Object`. But casting an `Object` to `Location` is still a checked cast, and will fail fast if wrong. Casting to `T` would be unchecked, in contrast.

Comment: @PaulBellora: thanks that clarifies it - I apparently did not grok what "Unchecked" was about - see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18724660/281545)

Answer (score 1):

From Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html)

> We are prepared to cope with ClassCastException s when there is a cast
>   expression in the source code, but we do not expect ClassCastException
>   s when we extract an element from a list of strings.  This sort of
>   unexpected ClassCastException is considered a violation of the
>   type-safety principle.  In order to draw attention to the potentially
>   unsafe cast the compiler issues an "unchecked" warning when it
>   translates the dubious cast expression.

So the answer to my first question is that the cast to `SomeType` will fail there and then if the classes are not compatible - while the `List<ScanResult> scanRes = (List<ScanResult>) data;` which at run time is just `List scanRes = (List) data;` won't fail if `data` is *any* List implementation - but might result in a CCE in a remote and completely unrelated part of the codebase - hence it will be real difficult to debug - hence the warning.

Another way to put it (by @erickson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367673/281545%5C)) :

> By doing your own cast up front, you're "complying with the warranty terms" of Java generics: if a `ClassCastException` is raised, it will be associated with a cast in the source code, not an invisible cast inserted by the compiler.