# The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Student>, when using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, unchecked-conversion

I have this piece of code that gives the warning mentioned in the title:

```
List<Student> studentList = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("indexNumber", indexNum))
    .list();
```

I've read the thread [How do I fix "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion...'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion) and there's a great solution by @BrunoDeFraine:

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
    List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
    for(Object o: c)
      r.add(clazz.cast(o));
    return r;
}
```

then I can just do this:

```
List<SyndEntry> entries = castList(SyndEntry.class, sf.getEntries());
```

This works great, but in my case I have Criteria as argument, not class and collection.
My question is, can this method be adapted to have criteria as argument, or should I simply use @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Comment: You want to cast a Criteria object?  That makes no sense.  `criteria.list()` returns a List, so I'm not sure where the gap is.  That method is odd anyways, you don't gain any compile-time type-safety (it will still only fail at runtime if something is wrong), and it could slow things down, especially if the list is long.  I'd just use `@SuppressWarnings` or live with the warning.

Comment: @Taylor please make this comment an answer so I can accept it (if you want, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comment:
You want to cast a Criteria object? That makes no sense. `criteria.list()` returns a List, so you could just use that.

The `castList` method is odd anyways, you don't gain any compile-time type-safety (it will still only fail at runtime if something is wrong), and it could slow things down, especially if the list is long. I'd just use @SuppressWarnings or live with the warning.