# createQuery Syntax error on token ";", , expected

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

hi i'm working with a spring mvc project using jpa data and i am having this problem, when ytry to do this assign `results =  query.getResultList();` in gives me a syntax error in the upper line in this case the upper line is  `Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c");` it doesnt matter where i put the assign line it always gives me a error in the direct upper line where i put this line `results =  query.getResultList();` even if i put it down a simple line like this `int number = 2;` it gives and error

this is the error that eclipse spring-tools-suite gives me

```
Syntax error on token ";", , expected
```

this is the class where i am trying to do the createQuery

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@Service
public class ServicePerson {

@Autowired private RepositoryPerson personRepo;


    EntityManager em = null;
    List<Object[]> results = null; 

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c"); <--// ERROR AT THIS LINE
    results =  query.getResultList();
```

When i try to create my query it gives me a syntax error in the upper line in this case in the upper line this is the error "Syntax error on token ";", , expected"

Comment: Your query code needs to be in a method, it can't just be in the class body.

Comment: You find the explanation for the warning here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion

Comment: Did you set the dialect? something like: `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect"/>`

Comment: yes this is my `jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);`

Comment: Is this issue resolved or you still getting error ?

Comment: just the waring that i mention before but is ok.