# The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List< CategoryTypes >

Tags: liferay-6

I have this code :

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(OpenBoard.class);
DynamicQuery categoryQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(CategoryTypes.class);
User user=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(PortalUtil.getUserId(request));
List<CategoryTypes> category_list= null;
categoryQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("categoryTarget",String.valueOf("O")));
category_list=CategoryTypesLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(categoryQuery);            
the last line generates the warning
```

> "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to
>   List< CategoryTypes >"

How can I fix my code to remove this warning?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this to know more about asking a  question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion...'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

First add this method into your class:

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
    List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
    for(Object o: c)
      r.add(clazz.cast(o));
    return r;
}
```

Than try this:

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(OpenBoard.class);
DynamicQuery categoryQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(CategoryTypes.class);
User user=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(PortalUtil.getUserId(request));
categoryQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("categoryTarget",String.valueOf("O")));
List<CategoryTypes> category_list = castList(CategoryTypes.class, CategoryTypesLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(categoryQuery));
```

bibliography: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2848268/6676203