# Getting type safety conversion

Tags: java

Getting type safety conversion warning from below code.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> batchValues = new ArrayList<>(entity.size());

int[] noOfRecords = namedParameterJDBCTemplate.batchUpdate(updateQuery, batchValues.toArray(new Map[entity.size()]));
```

> batchValues.toArray(new Map[entity.size()]) Type safety: The
>   expression of type Map[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to
>   Map[]

If I used `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` this annotation on method level then it's resolved the issue.

What is the best solution to resolve the issue?

Comment: Maybe you could adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2848268/180100 but using the annotation is OK if you know what you do. You could also use an array for batchValues (you know the size so..)

Comment: Dupliicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131652/generic-array-creation-error (which is marked as a duplicate, but actually isn't).

Answer (score 0):

The method declaration is `<T> T[] toArray(T[] to)`

The assignment for a variable is typed as Map[] but as reference in methods it is Object[]

Since the declaration accepts `<T>` you can simple do when as parameter:

```
batchValues.<Map<String, Object>>toArray(new Map<String, Object>[entity.size()])
```

Comment: An untyped `Map` will generate an “unchecked” warning.