# raw vs. generic List using apache commons-collections

Tags: java, maven

In a Java v8 Maven v3.6.3 project using apache commons-collections v3.2 dependency. I have the following code:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**java code**

```
public static List<String> list = org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils.union(A, B);
```

...where A & B are `List<String>`.

From this, I get in Eclipse the expected compiler warning for unchecked conversion between raw List and generic List. I understand what it is, but what puzzles me is that the apache docs for [union()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#union-java.util.List-java.util.List-) tell me that that method returns `List<E>`. But my compiler doesn't seem to recognize that...and if I click on the ListUtils declaration to view it locally, sure enough it's

```
public static List union()...    // a raw type indeed
```

I confirmed via `mvn dependency:tree` that commons-collections 3.2 is present.

I have seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion) as a possible solution, but first:

Am I reading the apache docs wrong in thinking that union returns `List<E>`?

Comment: Apache Commons Collections only got generics support in version 4.0. Your 3.2 version predates that and as such only deals in raw types (see [its JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#union(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)). The 4.0 release uses `org.apache.commons.collections4` as the package name (probably to allow use of the 4 release even if v3 is a transitive dependency somehow).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - That would make sense. Thanks

Comment: You could just get rid of ListUtils, and use `Stream.concat(A.stream(), B.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`.