# How to get java.util.Map from hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am wondering what is the best way to get map array from hibernate query. Google says to iterate query.list(), and create/put objects into empty map array.
I guess there would be some elegant and efficient way to do this. Could somebody give me idea?

Comment: What would be the keys and what would be the values of this Map? Any attempt to answer this question would require a heck of a lot more information about what you'd like to have happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Hibernate return a collection of result objects OTHER than a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416970/can-hibernate-return-a-collection-of-result-objects-other-than-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Hibernate Documentation - 15.6. The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select):

You can assign aliases to selected expressions using as:

```
select max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n
from Cat cat
```

This is most useful when used together with select new map:

```
select new map( max(bodyWeight) as max, min(bodyWeight) as min, count(*) as n )
from Cat cat
```

This query returns a Map from aliases to selected values.

Comment: if you execute the hql using createQuery.list it will just return a list.  Each element of the list is a map with one key & one value.  So it is not returning a map it is returning a list of maps...am I missing something...