# Retrieve a Map<String,<T>> from a table

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x

I read some informative posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876724/how-to-return-mapkey-value-with-hql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292597/how-to-get-java-util-map-from-hibernate-query) but I am still confused.

Hibernate version is **4.3.11**
The MySQL Account table is :

```
Field           Type            Null    Key
Id              int(11)         NO      PRI
Reference       varchar(20)     NO      UNI     
Balance         decimal(10,5)   NO          
Currency        varchar(3)      NO          
Valid           tinyint(1)      NO          
Type            varchar(20)     YES
```

The AccountDaoImpl method :

```
@Override
```

Accepts a collection of valid account references
@param accountReferences
@return A java.util.Map with account reference as key and the Account entity as value
@throws DaoException

```
public Map<String, Account> getAccountsByReferences(Collection<String> accountReferences) throws DaoException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (accountReferences == null || accountReferences.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        if (accountReferences.size() > Constants.MAX_ACCOUNTS_SIMULT) {
            throw new DaoException("Please query " + Constants.MAX_ACCOUNTS_SIMULT + " at a time");
        }

        String accountByRefSQL = "SELECT new map(acc.reference,acc ) FROM Account acc WHERE acc.reference IN (:accountReferences)";

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            Query query = session.createQuery(accountByRefSQL).setParameterList("accountReferences", accountReferences);

            return findMany(query);

        } catch (DaoException daoException) {
            log.error("DaoException in AccountDaoImpl.findAccountByReference(...)", daoException);
            throw daoException;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.error("HibernateException in AccountDaoImpl.findAccountByReference(...)", e);
            throw new DaoException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

The findMany() method is in the parent GenericDao :

```
public List<T> findMany(Query query) throws DaoException {
        try {
            List<T> t;
            t = (List<T>) query.list();
            return t;
        } catch (HibernateException hibernateExecption) {
            log.error("Hibernate Exception in GenericHibernateDaoImpl.findMany(...)", hibernateExecption);
            throw new DaoException(hibernateExecption.getMessage());
        } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
            log.error("RuntimeException in GenericHibernateDaoImpl.findMany(...)", runtimeException);
            throw new DaoException(runtimeException.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

There are two questions :

1. As per the threads I mentioned, the call is correct(I dunno how!)
2. The threads state that **the Query will return will return a List of Map** - I don't understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reply from [this forum thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043299).

> You are trying to cast a List into a Map. [Check out the map()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause-dynamic-map-instantiation-example) select
>   syntax. The Map is supposed to wrap the ResultSet, but the query
>   returns a List.
>
> I suggest you return a List and then build the Map using a simple
>   iteration.