# Return a set instead of list with hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, database, hibernate, list, set

```
criteria = createCriteria("employee");  
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "John"));  
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("city"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("state"));
List result = criteria.list();
```

This statement returns a list of `Employee` objects. How can I make it return a `Set` of Employee objects instead, in order to remove duplicate data?

I understand I can achieve this by creating a set out of the returned list like below, but then I would lose the sorting order of the list. And I don't want to have to write code to sort the set.

```
Set<Employee> empSet = new HashSet<Employee>(result);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `LinkedHashSet`? That will preserve the order, i think.

Comment: Maybe that should help: [can-hibernate-return-a-collection-of-result-objects-other-than-a-list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416970/can-hibernate-return-a-collection-of-result-objects-other-than-a-list)

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731723/how-to-add-distinct-in-hibernate-criteria

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's possible to return a `Set` using `Criteria` based on the javadoc. However, if you want to remove duplicate data, why don't add a `Projections.distinct(...)` to your existing `Criteria` to remove the duplicates?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html

**UPDATE**

For example, if you want to apply a `SELECT DISTINCT` on the employee name (or some identifier(s)) to get a list of unique employees, you can do something like this:-

```
List result = session.createCriteria("employee")
            .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("name")))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "John"))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("city"))
            .addOrder(Order.asc("state"))
            .list();
```

This way, you don't really need to worry about using `Set` at all.

Comment: Do we get the list of employee object or just employee Id? I tried using this code and it would just return the list of id instead of list of object.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments and [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) suggest, you have to return a `List` from [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html).  Therefore, your only option is to remove uniques after the fact.  As KepaniHaole said, you should use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you want to preserve order.