# Add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in generics to single line generates eclipse compiler error

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-errors, suppress-warnings

I have stumbled upon a strange behavior that I don't understand.

I have to cast a String to a generic and it's producing a warning.

```
Type safety : Unchecked cast from String to T
```

- If I add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`above the method declaration
  it works fine.
- If I add it above the assignment it produces a compiler error in
  eclipse.

This works fine.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T search(final String query){
 T returnValue = null;
 ...
 if(returnValue instanceof String){
  returnValue = (T) collection.getString(attrName);
 }
```

This don't work fine.

```
public <T> T search(final String query){
 T returnValue = null;
 ...
 if(returnValue instanceof String){
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Compiler error: "returnValue cannot be resolved to a type"
  returnValue = (T) collection.getString(attrName);
 }
```

Any idea what's causing the discrepancy between the two methods of suppressing the warning?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can't have annotation on arbitrary expressions (yet? Maybe they'll add it later on).

You *can* however have annotations on local variable declarations.

So what the compiler *tries* to do here is to interpret `returnValue` as a type (as that's the only thing that can follow an annotation inside a method body) and fails.

Putting the annotation at the *declaration* of `returnValue` does not help in this case. You can however create a new local variable where you perform the cast in the initializer and annotate that.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T string = (T) collection.getString(attrName);
returnValue = string;
```

Comment: Came here, because I did not understand the error _"Syntax error on token 'results', VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"_ in Eclipse. Your explanation what the compiler tries and why it fails is great! Just adding this comment, in case anybody else searches for this syntax error.