# Avoiding Type Safety Warnings Using Hibernate Query.list()

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

Is it possible to avoid cast warnings after using createQuery().list?

```
//Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<User>
List<User> user = (List<User>) session.createQuery("select u from User u").list();
```

I expected to find a method that specified the target object via generic parameter or method parameter such as the following:

```
List<User> user = session.createQuery("select u from User u").list(User.class);
```

Comment: It seems the sad answer is that there is no easy/clean way of doing this through the Hibernate API.  Would love the insight from the design reasons why this is the case if intentional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important thing to remember is that **warnings are due to your compiler, not hibernate** - you can tell your compiler to ignore unimplemented generics.  By using HQL, we are querying for data in a type safe way that, unfortunately, java does not have the ability to verify.

There are a lot of ways to get around the syntactical ugliness of hibernate casting , like :

1) use @suppressWarnings where casting or

2) use the Collections.checkedList method to create the new list.

See also : [How to avoid type safety warnings with Hibernate HQL results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results)

Comment: I found this question after further searching.  Would have found it sooner but I was searching for "strongly typed hibernate query" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the warnings if you use an `EntityManager`, but not sure if it makes things any nicer:

```
EntityManager em = provider.get(); // your code will probably be different here
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(type); // your Class<T>
Root<T> root = query.from(type); // your Class<T>
query.select(root);
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
typedQuery.getResultList(); // List<T>
```

**Edit:** obviously, there are nicer ways of setting this out...

Answer (score 0):

Since JPA 2.0 , EntityManager has added following overloaded createQuery()/createNamedQuery() methods that return TypedQuery to solve the propblem:

```
TypedQuery<T> entityManager.createQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery)


TypedQuery<T> entityManager.createQuery(java.lang.String qlString, java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)


TypedQuery<T> entityManager.createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)
```

Example:

```
@Repository
public class UsersRepositoryImpl implements IUsersRepository {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName="SPRING_BOOT_JPA_DS_PU")

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> listUser() {
        String queryString = "SELECT U FROM " + User.class.getName() + " U";
        // Query query =entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
        // Use TypedQuery instead of Query
        // Requires JPA 2.0
        TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, User.class);
        List<User> resultList = query.getResultList();

        return resultList;
    }


    }
```