# How to check type of List of Users returned from Query object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

To retrieve data from database using Hibernate, I use the following syntax :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User where name=? and password=?");
query.setString(0,user.getName());
query.setString(1,user.getPassword());

List list = query.list();           // Line 1
```

Line 1 shows warning: *"List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized."*

Now, if I add generics using:

```
List<User> list = (List<User>) query.list();
```

This again gives warning: *"Unchecked type conversion."*

How do I check the type of List of Users?

Comment: The Hibernate API is not generified yet. So warnings are unavoidable. Your second snippet is OK. You may suppress the warning with an annotation like Sandeep Pathak suggests.

Comment: Take a look to this question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651176/avoiding-type-safety-warnings-using-hibernate-query-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but seems okay to me .

You might want to use

```
@SuppressWarnings (value="unchecked")
```

Answer (score 1):

The information about template parameter type is erased in runtime. This is called **type erasure**. So, you just have to know in advance the type you are casting to. To avoid compiler warning, you may use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Also, you may try the *Hibernate Typesafe Criteria*, have a look [here](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/jpamodelgen.html).