# Avoid type safety warnings with Hibernate criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

```
final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
final List<MyClass> myClassList = crit.list();
```

results in this :
*Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List*

Is their a method to remove the warning, as I get an error using this :

```
final List<MyClass> myClassList = Collections.checkedList(MyClass.class, crit.list());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

before the declaration...

Note that this will only suppress the warning - it won't do anything to make the code safer. In this case, I'd personally be happy enough about this; I'd trust Hibernate to do the right thing.

Comment: @EvertonAgner: I was going by the "remove the warning" bit of the question.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know... I meant that we should know if he wants to solve the issue or if he just has a OCD about warnings........ As I do *lol

Comment: If you depend on a 3rd-party API that returns untyped collections, there's not much you can usefully do other than suppress the warning. And add a comment explaining why you can guarantee that the collection's elements are really of the right type.

Comment: Btw, if he has a lot of methods in which he should need to place the annotation on it, he could just place it in the Class declaration (it would apply to any member of it).

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
final List<MyClass> myClassList 
    = Collections.checkedList(MyClass.class, crit.list());
```

you just need to inverse the order of the arguments to `checkedList()`.

Btw you could static import the method to make your code more concise.
Also btw, I didn't know about `checkedList()` - thanks for the heads-up!

**Edit**: `checkedList()` doesn't do what you want - as I should have realised if I'd thought about it properly before answering.

`checkedList()` will check the types of any elements added to the list and fail immediately. As opposed to a normal list which would allow you to put the wrong types in, and fail only upon retrieval. In your case it makes no difference since you're not going to insert items yourself (I guess).

Jon Skeet's answer (`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`) is the right one.

Comment: I still get the warning ... after reversing the paramters

Comment: Sorry - didn't look at it carefully enough. Going to edit my reply with better information.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best way to avoid type safety warning is as `Matt Quail` says in this post: [How to avoid type safety warnings with Hibernate HQL results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results) , writing a cast-helper, but with Criteria instead of Query, like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> listAndCast(Criteria crit) {
  List<T> list = crit.list();
  return list;
}
```

And only you have to call this method:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = listAndCast(crit);
```

Greetings!