# Can someone please explain this java generics syntax?

Tags: java, generics

```
public static <T> List<T> listAndCast(Query query) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> list = query.list();
        return list;
    }
```

In the following line:

```
public static <T> List<T> listAndCast(Query query) {
```

Why do we need `<T>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<T>` tells Java that it is a generic method that defines its own type parameter, instead of relying on one defined for the entire class, e.g.

`public class Stuff<T> {}`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really help at all.

At the call site, it allows you to assign the result to a `List` with any type parameter, which isn't very type-safe. All this code simply bestows a false sense of security on you. If it returns, for example, a `List<String>` then as written you will be allowed to assign that result to a `List<Integer>` and you won't know you've screwed up until much later on (when you try and access an element of the `List` and assign it to an `Integer`) and the implicit cast blows up in your face.

Generally, if a generic method (e.g. one which has its own type parameters separate from the class it's a member of) only uses its type parameter once and/or only uses it for the return value, it is a total waste of time!

Comment: Unfortunately this is the least painful way of dealing with legacy API that returns plain `List`, but you _know_ that it really returns `List<Foo>`.

Comment: I agree with @mitchnull. Came across the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results and Thanks for the insight on what's going on here!

Comment: That's probably the only valid use

Answer (score 0):

That's what tells java that listAndCast is a generic method that depends on the T type.

side note: I prefer this implementation for this problem, as it's more generic:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> list_cast(List<?> orig) {
    return (List<T>)orig;
}
```

Comment: came across this and thought you might be interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/115952/280924

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `<T>`, but it does stop compiler warnings. The compiler will infer that a `List<Object>` will be returned (it has no other information about the type that will be returned).

It's essentially the same as:

```
public static List listAndCast(Query query)
```

Without warnings about raw types.

`<T>` might be useful if a passed argument was parameterized with `<T>`, e.g:

```
public static <T> List<T> listAndCast(Query<T> query)
```

Comment: How do you know the target type of the cast if you don't pass the type argument?