# Hibernate List warning;

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I have the following code on my Hibernate class:

```
public List<Something> getSomethingList(Integer[] ls){
    String sql = "FROM SOMETHING WHERE IDSOMETHING IN (:ls)";

    return this.getSession().createQuery(sql).setParameterList("ls", ls).list();
}
```

I Have an warning on the return line. The warning is the following:

```
Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<Something>
```

I know this is not a big issue but how can I solve this warning?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Option:
THIS:

```
 List<Permission> permissions = Collections.checkedList(Permission.class, this.getSession().createQuery(sql).setParameterList("ls", ls).list());
```

Should be like this:

```
List<Permission> permissions = Collections.checkedList(this.getSession().createQuery(sql).setParameterList("ls", ls).list(),Permission.class);
```

Second Option:

Use:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Personally, I like the second option.

Comment: The exact duplicate hold the answer as posted.

Comment: @danny.lesnik This is wrong. Look the modifications I did to your samples.

Comment: @fegol, Yes you are right, the position is different, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Prevent Eclipse from generating warnings for unavoidable problems**

In Eclipse, go to Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings and under Generic type, select the checkbox
`Ignore unavoidable generic type problems due to raw APIs`

This will turn off unnecessary warnings for similar problems like the one described above which are unavoidable.