# Avoid safety warnings with Hibernate HQL results?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

For example I have such query:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<MenuItems> listAllMenuItems() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<MenuItems> menuItems = null;
    try {

        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(MenuItems.class);
        menuItems = cr.list();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return menuItems;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid type safety warnings with Hibernate HQL results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Collections.checkedList()

```
List<MenuItems> cats = Collections.checkedList(cr.list(), MenuItems.class);
```

Or use @suppressWarnings, which you have specified in your code

Answer (score 1):

I think it will solve your answer

List menuItems = Collections.checkedList(cr.list(), MenuItems.class);

for full details check this thread

[How to avoid type safety warnings with Hibernate HQL results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results)