# How to user Hibernate with EntityManager instead of Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa, entitymanager

I recently had a similar issue as [this SOer had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results), where I was using Hibernate's `Query#list` object and getting compiler warnings for type safety.

Someone pointed out to me that I could use [`EntityManager#createQuery(String,Class<?>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) instead of Query#list to accomplish the same thing but have everything genericized correctly.

I've been searching for examples of using Hibernate directly with `EntityManager` but so far no luck. So I ask: how can I use the `EntityManager#createQuery` method in lieu of the `Query#list` method when doing a SELECT from Hibernate?

Comment: Those methods have completely different purposes.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis (+1) - so is it the case that Hibernate cannot be used with EntityManager? If so, why and what are the "completely different purposes"? Or, is it the case that it can be used with EntityManager, in which case, can you direct me to any documentation that explains how to use the two together? Thanks again!

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Hibernate's `Session`. It serves the same purpose as an `EntityManager`. `Session` has a `createQuery` method that uses HQL to create a `Query` object. You can then call `list()` on that object.

Comment: Oh, it appears to me you already know all this.

Comment: Yep ;-) Thanks again @SotiriosDelimanolis - so any ideas as to how to link these 2 ideas together, so I don't have to keep adding `@SuppressWarnings` all over my code?

Comment: There's a `hibernate-entitymanager` project on [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager). It might be Hibernate's implementation of that interface. Maybe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis that's *exactly* what I'm looking for. I'm trying to figure out how to use the `EntityManager` API (at runtime I'll be using the `hibernate-entitymanager` JAR that you mentioned) and Hibernate to create a properly-genericized Query object.