# What should I do with unchecked cast for criteria.list()?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, unchecked-cast

I have a criteria that is returning a list of strings `List<String>`.

I have following in the method

```
 return criteria.list();
```

But the code shows

```
 Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<String>
```

To avoid adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`
and to make sure the types are safely converted (not sure if I should really do it), I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results) and tried to add the solution to my code

```
 return Collections.checkedList(criteria.list(),List<String>);
```

but it shows another error as following:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<String>
    - Syntax error on token ">", Expression expected after this 
     token
```

- I do not know if I should really use Collections.checkedList
- If I should use it, then how to use it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code for the method that returns `criteria.list()`?

Answer (score 2):

**•I do not know if I should really use Collections.checkedList**

It is really not necessary in standard implementations, its purpose if mostly for debugging, or if you are receiving a list that you are unsure of and need to make sure it is typesafe(usually because of third party code) or generics have been used and you need to make sure the code is correct at this point as it will throw the exception here and identify what isn't of the correct type.

**•If I should use it, then how to use it?**

If you were to implement `Collections.checkedList` the two arguments are the list that is not typesafe and the class that you want a list of, in this case `String.class` not `List<String>`

```
return Collections.checkedList(criteria.list(), String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the method `criteria.list()` returns a `List<String>`, then the correct statement would be

```
return Collections.checkedList(criteria.list(), String.class);
```

A similar case applies for any other object, e.g. if the method returns a custom object of type `Criterion`, the answer would be

```
return Collections.checkedList(criteria.list(), Criterion.class);
```